# How to display all data in fdpf with the same

Tags: php, mysqli, fpdf

Hi guys i need your help i can't display all rows in FPDF with the same foreign key. I want to display all the rows with the drinfo_id = 10 in FPDF

```
   <?php
   require('fpdf.php');
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","dr");
   if($mysqli->connect_error)
  die("Database connection failed ".$mysql->connect_error);

  $pdf=new FPDF();
  $pdf->AddPage();

  $queryDritems = "select * from items where drinfo_id=10";
  $resultDritems = $mysqli->query($queryDritems);

  while($rowDritems = $resultDritems->fetch_assoc()){
  $description = $rowDritems['description'];

  $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
  $pdf->SetY(66);
  $pdf->SetX(5);
  $pdf->Cell(20,6,$description,0);  




  $pdf->Output();


 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed some Errors

For example: you write  `$pdf->Output();`in loop

```
 <?php
           require('fpdf.php');
            $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","dr");
           if($mysqli->connect_error)
          die("Database connection failed ".$mysql->connect_error);

          $pdf=new FPDF();
          $pdf->AddPage();

          $queryDritems = "select * from items where drinfo_id=10";
          $resultDritems = $mysqli->query($queryDritems);

          while($rowDritems = $resultDritems->fetch_assoc()){
          $description = $rowDritems['description'];

          $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
          $pdf->SetY(66);
          $pdf->SetX(5);
          $pdf->Cell(20,6,$description,0);  
        //   or
        //   $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
        // $pdf->SetY(26);
        // $pdf->SetX(45);
        // $pdf->MultiCell(20,6,$description,1);

         }

        $filename="PDF_FILE.pdf";
        $pdf->Output($filename,'F');
```

Comment: sir i want to display all rows with drinfo_id = 10. There is no syntax error in my code it only display one rows with drinfo_id = 10 not all rows with drinfo_id=10 displying

Comment: `$row_height = 6;
  $y_axis=65;
  while($rowDritems = $resultDritems->fetch_assoc()){
  $description = $rowDritems['description'];

  $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
  $pdf->SetY($y_axis);
  $pdf->SetX(5);
  $pdf->Cell(20,6,$description,0);  

  $y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;
 }`

Comment: dynamic setx and sety.. above code is working..  first you print fetch values to check data

Comment: sir how can i contact you if i need help :D

Comment: bilalahmed78600@gmail.com